# is there an scp/sftp client library available for flex?

Tags: apache-flex, sftp, scp

I need to send files securely from Adobe Air. In any other language, my first thought would be sftp/scp, but I don't see any libraries to do that in Flex.

I'm new to flex, so I'm not sure where to look for code examples and repos. It looks like the raw socket interface is available, so I could write one if no good examples exist. Of course, I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Any update on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an action script ftp project, but it seems to be no longer maintained. You can take a look [here](http://maliboo.pl/projects/FlexFTP/), maybe you can reuse some code.